# custom keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout, system-settings, xkb

I have created a custom Dvorak keyboard layout that I have used successfully under Ubuntu 16.04. Now I am trying to get it to work with Ubuntu 20.04.

Here are my steps:

1. I copy my layout file to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/dv-mac`
2. I add the following line to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst`

```
  dv_mac          us: Dvorak extended (similar to Mac OS X)
```

3. I add the following to the `<layoutList>` sections of `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xfree86.xml` and `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`

```xml
      <layout>
        <configItem>
        <name>dv-mac</name>
        <shortDescription>Dvorak</shortDescription>
        <description>Dvorak</description>
        <languageList>
          <iso639Id>eng</iso639Id>
        </languageList>
        </configItem>
        <variantList />
      </layout>
```

Here's where I put this block, as the first item in the `<layoutList>`, just after the `<modelList>`, at around line 1335:

```
...
    <model>
      <configItem>
       <name>teck229</name>
       <description>Truly Ergonomic Computer Keyboard Model 229 (Standard sized Alt keys, additional Super and Menu key)</description>
       <vendor>Megawin Technology</vendor>
     </configItem>
    </model>
  </modelList>
  <layoutList>
```

```xml
    <layout>
      <configItem>
        <name>dv-mac</name>
        <shortDescription>Dvorak</shortDescription>
        <description>Dvorak</description>
        <languageList>
          <iso639Id>eng</iso639Id>
        </languageList>
      </configItem>
      <variantList />
    </layout>
```

```
    <layout>
      <configItem>
        <name>us</name>
        <!-- Keyboard indicator for English layouts -->
        <shortDescription>en</shortDescription>
        <description>English (US)</description>
        <languageList>
          <iso639Id>eng</iso639Id>
        </languageList>
      </configItem>
...
```

I have noted that I use `dv_mac` in the xorg.lst file and 'dv-mac` (with a hyphen instead of an underscore) elsewhere, but apparently this worked both on Ubuntu 16.04 and a previous version of Ubuntu 20.04 that I installed.

However, this time, I cannot get the entry for my `Dvorak` keyboard to appear in the `Language and Region` settings.

Any help in finding where I have gone wrong this time will be much appreciated.

Comment: Oh yes. That was my first action.

Comment: I edited my `evdev.xml` file with the above, and it showed up for me as an item under all the _English_ menu items.

Comment: Where did you put it in evdev.xml? It doesn't appear for me, anywhere at all in the Languages and Regions settings.

Comment: I think I put it as the very last layout right before `</layoutList>` (around line 6322).